# Турка, джезва, кавоварка

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів, синоніми

*Чи є нормативним вживати слово **"турка"**, в значені посуду для варіння кави?*

У [Новітньому онлайному словнику української мови (2013-2018)](http://sum.in.ua/f/turka) зазначено

> **ТУРКА** Те саме, що джезва.
>   *Вона підігріває молоко, мостить на тацю турку з кавою, молочник, цукерничку й велику чашку..*    (Ірина Цілик, Родимки, 2012);
>
> **[ДЖЕЗВА](http://sum.in.ua/f/dzhezva)** Невелика завужена вгорі посудина з носиком та довгою ручкою для варіння кави по-турецьки; турка.

Інколи посуд для варіння кави називають **"кавоварка"**. На мою думку, **"кавоварка"** - це машина для варіння кави, але не посуд (підтвердення цього не знайшла).

***Чи нормативно використовувати всі три слова як повні синоніми?***

Answer (score 2):

У «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах маємо такі значення наведених слів:

> [КАВОВА́РКА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=163411&page=1259), и, ж.
>
> 1. Невеликий побутовий прилад для приготування кави. Каву готує модерна електрична гейзерна кавоварка. Я лишень спеціальною ложечкою засипаю її туди (з газ.); Про сніданок можна не хвилюватися — у потрібний час автоматично увімкнеться кавоварка, а мікрохвильова піч розігріє їжу (з мови реклами).
> 2. Посудина, в якій варять каву (у 3 знач.).
>
> ---
>
> [ДЖЕ́ЗВА](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=203725&page=748), и, ж. Посудина для готування кави по-турецьки. Віктор вийшов на кухню, повернувшись майже відразу з тацею, на якій парувала джезва з кавою і стояло два кухлики (О. Тесленко)

Щодо виникнення назви турка авторитетної розвідки не знайшла. Вірогідно, що походить вона від турків — назви народу, від якого прийшла до нас джезва. Така версія є і в немовознавчій [статті](https://harchi.info/blogs/san-ayt-j/vybyrayemo-turku-dlya-kavy).

Є ще один варіант:

> [КА́ВНИК](http://sum.in.ua/s/kavnyk), а, чол. Посудина, у якій варять або подають каву.

Отже, кавником і кавоваркою можна назвати і турецьку посудину для приготування кави, і будь-яку іншу з тією самою функцією. А електричний чи газовий пристрій — лише кавоваркою.

Answer (score 2):

Слово турка не зустрічається в СУМ-11, але воно є в [Вільному словнику](http://sum.in.ua/f/turka) української мови. Визначення:

> Те саме, що джезва.

Є там і джезва (слово прийшло в нашу мову із турецької):

Невелика завужена вгорі посудина з носиком та довгою ручкою для варіння кави по-турецьки; **турка**.

Є і стаття на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0), де пише:

> **Дже́зва** (тур. cezve з араб. جذوة‎), **інша назва ту́рка**

ЕСУМ не дає інформацію про походження слова "турка", але на сайті [Харчі Інфо](https://harchi.info/blogs/san-ayt-j/vybyrayemo-turku-dlya-kavy) (звичайно, я не стверджую, що це достовірна інформація) є така версія:

> **Турка** — це швидше народна і жартівлива назва, яка виникла через те, що про цей інструмент ми дізнались саме від турків. В оригіналі ж
>   він називається джезва — це адаптована назва слова тюркського
>   походження.

А згідно до російського сайту [z-terra](https://z-terra.ru/news/113/), то "турка" - це також є спрощення назви "джезва" і означає "турецька посуда". А в Європі "джезви" і "турки" називаються "ібрики". І це дійсно так, ось посилання на статтю про [ібрик](http://coffee.wikia.com/wiki/Ibrik) (вона англійською).

В українській мові ж є слово "кавник", але про це вже написала Оксана у своїй відповіді.  Додам, що ще є слово "[кофейник](http://sum.in.ua/s/kofejnyk)". А також мені ще вдалося знайти таку цікаву інформацію на форумі де саме обговорювали можливе походження слово "турка":

> Пошук по масиву книжок books.google не дає підказок для якоїсь
>   територіальної прив’язки ні в українській, ні в російській мові.
>   Джезва й турка трапляються спорадично з XIX ст., більш-менш реґулярно
>   з 1950-60-х років, а до словників заносяться тільки тепер, в останнє
>   десятиліття.
>
> До масового поширення кав’ярень і культури варіння потреби виділяти
>   назвою джезву не було. А посуд циліндричної форми з ручкою з XVIII ст.
>   називали просто кастроль, кастролка, кострулка. Я. Маркович у
>   щоденнику згадував, що привіз «кафейничок жовтий» (1744). Ще каву
>   заварювали в ківшиках, чайничках.
>
> Приклади з літератури, «доджезвового» і «дотуркового» періоду:
>   - «Сичав газ на кухні, в поруділій каструльці, закипаючи, повільно ворушилась димчастими струминками вчорашня чи позавчорашня кава» (А.
>   Мороз, 1964)
>   - «Коли кава закипіла, старий поставив каструльку на примурок...» (переклад, 1963)
>   - «Насипала в каструльку кави і залила її окропом...» (В. Шевчук, 1984).
>
> - «...чуєш, вже товчеться по кімнаті, вже брязкає чайничком, каву варить.» (1971)

Однак, слів кастроль, кастролка, кострулка, хоча очевидно, що всі вони пов'язанні із словом "кастрюля".

І нарешті є ще "[кавова машина](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)" і "[кавоварка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0)". І навіть сама Вікіпедії пише, що це різні речі. Наскільки я зрозумів різниця полягає у способі приготування даного напою. Врахуйте, що є ще "гейзерна кавоварка" або "[мока](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0))" і вона не електрична.